# Get JSON data from a PHP file to jQuery and put it on selectbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a big problem here. I want to receive data from a PHP file.

I do this:

```
$("#id_categoria").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo ROOT . '/control/functions.php'; ?>",
        data: "action=getsubbycat&id="+id,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

`alert(data)` returns `[{"id_subcategoria":"1","nome":"Port\u00e1teis"},{"id_subcategoria":"2","nome":"Desktop"}]`.

And how can I consume this? And put in `<option value="2">Desktop</option>`?

And why is `Portáteis` equal to `Port\u00e1teis`? Is it because my database is in UTF-8?

Comment: Where do you want to put <option value="2">Desktop</option> ?

Comment: there are two distinct questions here. One is about javascript/JQuery, the other about PHP/MySQL. You should split them up into two questions. And, like @3nigma pointed out, you need to go back and accept answers to the questions you've already asked (assuming your question has been answered). Doing so would make the community much more likely to help you out.

Comment: can you show the result you are getting after parseJSON  ???

Comment: i want to put in $('#id_subcategoria')

Comment: @littletipz the result of parseJSON is [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @3nigma: You did magic :) He accepted my answer :p

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to turn the string into a JSON object, then either build an object to insert into DOM using JQuery, or document.write() the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var new_data = $.parseJSON(data)
```

to get the object.

Now you can use `object.nome`, etc.

Comment: Dont worry about UTF conversion ------- it will be maintained

Comment: var new_data =     $.parseJSON(data)

and i try new_data.nome just return me = undefined why?

Comment: in success block you are trying this ? I mean you have written var new_data = $.parseJSON(data) in success block? Just console.log(new_data) and check what it is printing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

And when you want `nome`, try the following.

```
alert(new_data[0].nome);
```

Comment: that works nice THANKS now is read all array and get id_subcategoria, nome and put it on my select thanks :)